# jasypt interferes with server startup logging and AbstractFailureAnalyzer in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

Recently I integrated Jasypt in my Spring Boot project, and the project still works fine connecting to DB, MQ, and Kafka. Unfortunately I just found out that since then, logback does not work during the startup of the server (it still works once startup is complete), and also the failure analyzers quit working as well (for DB, MQ, and Kafka connection problem detection).
Here is what I added in Gradle script:

```
implementation('com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.2')
```

Here is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataRiverApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DataRiverApplication.class, args);

        LOGGER.info(INFO_APP_START);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
            LOGGER.info(name);
        }
    }
        
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(DataRiverApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Note that in the main class the `LOGGER.info` and `System.out.println` used to work just fine before this code change.

This is what my failure analyzer looks like:

```
public class MqFailureAnalyzer extends AbstractFailureAnalyzer<JMSException> {

    @Override
    protected FailureAnalysis analyze(Throwable rootFailure, JMSException cause) {
        LOGGER_ERROR.error(ERROR_APPLICATION_START_FAILURE + "JMSException" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(cause));
        return new FailureAnalysis(getDescription(cause), getAction(cause), cause);
    }

    String getDescription(JMSException ex) {
        return String.format(ex.getMessage());
    }

    String getAction(JMSException ex) {
        return String.format("Check MQ conenction details in conf/mq.properties.");
    }

}
```

which is registered in `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` as follows:

```
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=start.DatabaseFailureAnalyzer,start.MqFailureAnalyzer,start.KafkaFailureAnalyzer
```

Again it used to work but ever since the Jasypt integration, it no longer gets called when there is a startup failure. Here are the relevant properties in my db.properties:

```
spring.datasource.password=ENC(51TnfL6ieqAZcx9/WAXbnJRfpAerLoyPoFsOmKKFNODCemFDYSQ4EJc6Cqdyd/05)
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.RandomIvGenerator
```

Here are the relevant properties in kafka.properties:

```
kafka.security.protocol=SSL
kafka.ssl.truststore.location=kafka.jks
kafka.ssl.truststore.password=ENC(9m7qPYDi7YEKSw108WQwyvF0ruH7f1KBPLV3GL/Jlsi0XRxL+KHufCbCisdA9p+G)

kafka.ssl.keystore.location=kafka.jks
kafka.ssl.keystore.password=ENC(9m7qPYDi7YEKSw108WQwyvF0ruH7f1KBPLV3GL/Jlsi0XRxL+KHufCbCisdA9p+G)

kafka.ssl.key.password=ENC(9m7qPYDi7YEKSw108WQwyvF0ruH7f1KBPLV3GL/Jlsi0XRxL+KHufCbCisdA9p+G)
```

Here are the properties from catalina.properties for MQ:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword.encrypted=5MGKqSfK57P9MuFOi1D2gtaSnp3JiaveVq3DZDAtcfenYqBjMMjdpeLDv7Xv/yO2
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword.encrypted=5MGKqSfK57P9MuFOi1D2gtaSnp3JiaveVq3DZDAtcfenYqBjMMjdpeLDv7Xv/yO2
```

The decryption for MQ is a manual process, different from DB and Kafka:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:classpath" })
public class MqConfig {

    static {
        JasyptEncryptor.setPassword(System.getenv(ENV_VAR_JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD));

        System.setProperty(PROP_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, JasyptEncryptor.decrypt(System.getProperty(PROP_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED)));
        System.setProperty(PROP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, JasyptEncryptor.decrypt(System.getProperty(PROP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED)));
    }
```

Like I said, these things just start failing silently. I don't get any exceptions at all.
Can someone give me some idea what I can look at?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So I have pinpointed the problem to be with the static loading of the password for MQ. Once I have backed out of the static code, then everything starts to work as usual. I am still looking for an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem by moving the static code into a private method:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:mq.properties" })
public class MqConfig {

    private boolean envSet = false;

    private void setEnvVariables() {
        if (!envSet) {
            JasyptEncryptor.setPassword(System.getenv(ENV_VAR_JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD));

            System.setProperty(PROP_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, JasyptEncryptor.decrypt(System.getProperty(PROP_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED)));
            System.setProperty(PROP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, JasyptEncryptor.decrypt(System.getProperty(PROP_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_ENCRYPTED)));

            envSet = true;
        }
    }
```

Once I start calling this private method from within the bean configuration methods, the problem goes away.